# What is the best quick repair for a drain pipe?

Tags: repair, pipe, drainage, crack, drain-waste-vent

In particular, a cast iron drain pipe. It doesn't have to be pretty, but needs to be effective and should last until it can be fixed properly.

Comment: What about one of these pipe clamps? they use them on submarines and aircraft carriers, I'm sure they would hold a drain together.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xm9SSagYr4I

Comment: @Tester101, this is the perfect answer.  Add it a as an answer and I'll upvote you.  They sale these in Lowes or HomeDepot for $5-$10 and they work well until the pipe can be properly fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used [Denso Tape](http://www.denso.net/densotape/index.htm) and wrapped it tightly around the pipe - no leaks so far.

Disclaimer: it's awful stuff to work with - several pairs of disposable rubber gloves highly recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how and where it broke it going to affect what you can use.  I'm going to assume you're not looking for a suggestion of duct tape.

For long straight sections, where I had to cut a pipe, I've used [rubber pipe connectors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0031R9GPY).  You just slip it on one side of the break, align the pipes, and slip it over the break and tighten down the hose clamps.

There also exist [pipe wraps that harden](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00383YKCU) to do temporary repairs, that you can find in most hardware stores, but I've never used it.

I've used [epoxy putty](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BRQ0TW) when I had a leak right at a coupling, so I wasn't able to get wrap something tightly right where it was.  You just knead it together, press it into the leak, and wait for it to set up.

Answer (score 1):

**Temporary fix:** You can tightly wrap a rubber band around the pipe.  Since there is no pressure in the drain pipes, that will work just fine, unless the pipe gets clogged and filled up with sewage (and even in this case the pressures would be small enough for such a fix to work).

My parents' apartment has a cracked cast iron kitchen drainage pipe.  The rubber band was placed there more than 20 years ago: still works.  You shouldn't probably try to beat this record :)

Comment: When I moved into my house, the cleanout for the sewer was in an area of the basement that wasn't well lit.  Upon closer inspection, it had a plastic grocery bag over it, and then a layer of duct tape.  I have no idea how long it might've been there.  But the problem isn't just water leakage; you can also get sewer gasses into the house.

Answer (score 1):

See this [article](http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/asktoh/question/0,,1141241,00.html).  For a quick temporary fix you can use a repair sleeve, or clamp.

Answer (score 0):

Purchase 14" x 6' length of shower liners.  It comes in 6' widths so you have to buy the 6' but it only takes 14" to wrap around the pipe.  If the section of the damage is smaller than 14", then you could buy a smaller piece.  At my plumbing store it is sold by the square ft. for $2.  So, for the piece that I stated at the beginning, it cost me $7.  Then take some roofing tar and place it in the middle of the patch  where the leak is.  Then  use big hose clamps to make a tight seal at both ends.